# Symbolic Calculus and Integration in Python

Tags: python, numerical-methods, symbolic-math, numerical-integration

I am trying to numerically compute a double integral.
The issue is that (I think) I need a mix of symbolic integration and numerical integration.
The integral looks something like this:

[image]

I cannot use numpy.integrate because it is not just a double integral because of the power (1/a) in the middle.
I cannot get a number for the innermost integral (to then raise to the power) because it ends up being a function that depends on x which I would then need to integrate.

I tried with symbolic calculus, using a nested sym.integrate like here

`sym.integrate((sym.integrate(sym.exp(-(w**2)/(2*sigmaw)-alpha*((x-w)**2)/(2*sigma)),(w,-sym.oo, sym.oo)))**(1/alpha),(x,-sym.oo, sym.oo))`

however, it just spits back the expression itself and no number.
I think I would need to get a symbolic expression for the inner integral to use as a function for numerical integration.

Is it even possible?
If not in python, with another language like R?

Any experience with things of this sort?

Comment: You might need to use Mathematica for this.

Answer (score 2):

I worked with Maxima (https://maxima.sourceforge.io) since OP seems to be saying the exact system used isn't too important.

The integrand is just a product of Gaussian bumps, so its integral over the real line is not too hard. Maxima doesn't have the strongest integrator in the world, but anyway it seems to handle this problem okay.

Start by assuming all the parameters are positive; if not specified, Maxima will ask for the sign during the calculation.

```
(%i2) assume (alpha > 0, sigmaw > 0, sigma > 0);
(%o2)          [alpha > 0, sigmaw > 0, sigma > 0]
```

Define the inner integrand.

```
(%i3) I: exp(-(w**2)/(2*sigmaw)-alpha*((x-w)**2)/(2*sigma));
                                   2        2
                      alpha (x - w)        w
                   (- --------------) - --------
                         2 sigma        2 sigmaw
(%o3)            %e
```

Compute the inner integral.

```
(%i4) I1: integrate (I, w, minf, inf);
(%o4) (sqrt(2) sqrt(%pi) sqrt(sigma) sqrt(sigmaw)
                            2
                     alpha x
           - ------------------------
             2 alpha sigmaw + 2 sigma
         %e                          )/sqrt(alpha sigmaw + sigma)
```

The pretty-printer (ASCII art) display is hard to read here, maybe this 1-d representation makes more sense. `grind` produces the 1-d display.

```
(%i5) grind(%);
(sqrt(2)*sqrt(%pi)*sqrt(sigma)*sqrt(sigmaw)
        *%e^-((alpha*x^2)/(2*alpha*sigmaw+2*sigma)))
 /sqrt(alpha*sigmaw+sigma)$
(%o5)                         done
```

Define the outer integrand.

```
(%i7) I2: I1^(1/alpha);
           1          1            1             1
        -------    -------      -------       -------
        2 alpha    2 alpha      2 alpha       2 alpha
(%o7) (2        %pi        sigma        sigmaw
                      2
                     x                                       1
        - ------------------------                        -------
          2 alpha sigmaw + 2 sigma                        2 alpha
      %e                          )/(alpha sigmaw + sigma)
```

Compute the outer integral. The final result is named `foo` here.

```
(%i9) foo: integrate (I2, x, minf, inf);
             1              1            1             1
          ------- + 1/2  -------      -------       -------
          2 alpha        2 alpha      2 alpha       2 alpha
(%o9) (%pi              2        sigma        sigmaw
                                                             1
                                                          -------
                                                          2 alpha
    sqrt(2 alpha sigmaw + 2 sigma))/(alpha sigmaw + sigma)
```

Evaluate the outer integral for specific values of the parameters.

```
(%i10) ev (foo, alpha = 3, sigma = 3/7, sigmaw = 7/4);
                   1/6  1/6  1/6    1/3    2/3
                  2    3    7    159    %pi
(%o10)            ----------------------------
                            sqrt(14)
(%i11) float(%);
(%o11)                  5.790416728790489
```

Compute a numerical approximation. Note `quad_qagi` is suitable for infinite intervals.

```
(%i12) ev (quad_qagi (lambda([x], quad_qagi (I, w, minf, inf)[1]^(1/alpha)), x, minf, inf),
           alpha = 3, sigma = 3/7, sigmaw = 7/4);
(%o12)  [5.790416728790598, 7.216782674725913E-9, 270, 0]
```

Looks like that supports the symbolic result.

```
(%i13) first(%) - %o11;
(%o13)                1.092459456231154E-13
```

The outer integral again, in 1-d display which might be useful for copying into another program:

```
(%i14) grind(foo);
(%pi^(1/(2*alpha)+1/2)*2^(1/(2*alpha))*sigma^(1/(2*alpha))
                      *sigmaw^(1/(2*alpha))
                      *sqrt(2*alpha*sigmaw+2*sigma))
 /(alpha*sigmaw+sigma)^(1/(2*alpha))$
(%o14)                        done
```

I recommend pretty strongly to try to get to a symbolic result if possible; numerical integration is often tricky. In the example given, if it turned out that you could only do the inner integral but not the outer one, that would still be a pretty big win. You could plug the symbolic solution for the inner integral into a numerical approximation for the outer one.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I will look into it. I tried a bunch of combinations. Getting a symbolic result for the inner integral, combining numpy and sympy with lambdify, nothing worked so far, but I will try Maxima! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Numerical integration works by sampling the integrand at some values of the argument. In particular, the Newton-Cotes formulas sample uniformly, while different flavors of Gaussian integration sample irregularly.

So in your case, the integrator will require an evaluation of the inner integral for various values of x to integrate on x, implying each time a numerical integration on w with known x.

Note that as your domain is unbounded, you will have to use a change of variable to make it finite.

---

If the inner integral has an analytical expression, you can of course use it and integrate numerically on x.

Comment: About unbounded intervals, algorithm QAGI in QUADPACK handles the change of variables automatically (and then applies Gauss-Kronrod, as with the other QUADPACK functions). QUADPACK was originally Fortran; I'm pretty sure it is present in Scipy or Numpy, I forget which.

Answer (score 1):

this doesn't answer your question but it will surely help you, as other have already pointed out other useful tools.

for the integration at hand, you don't really need to do symbolic integration.

numerical integration is simply summing on a defined finite grid, and integrating over w is simply summing over the w axis, same as x.

the main problem is how to choose the integration grid, since it cannot be infinite, for gaussians I'd say at least 10 times their sigma for as low error as you can get, as for the grid spacing, I'd make it as small as you can wait for it to run.
so for the above integration, this would be equivalent, make sure you don't increase the grid steps until you have a picture of how much memory it will need, or else your pc will hang.

```py
import numpy as np

# define constants
sigmaw = 0.1
sigma = 0.1
alpha = 0.2

# define grid
max_w = 2
min_w = -max_w
min_x = -3
max_x = -min_x
steps_w = 2000  # don't increase this too much or you'll run out of memory
steps_x = 1000  # don't increase this too much or you'll run out of memory
dw = (max_w - min_w) / steps_w
dx = (max_x - min_x) / steps_x
x_vec = np.linspace(min_x, max_x, steps_x)
w_vec = np.linspace(min_w, max_w, steps_w)
x, w = np.meshgrid(x_vec, w_vec, sparse=True)

# do integration
inner_term = np.exp(-(w ** 2) / (2 * sigmaw) - alpha * ((x - w) ** 2) / (2 * sigma))
inner_integral = np.sum(inner_term, axis=0) * dw
del inner_term  # to free some memory
inner_integral_powered = inner_integral ** (1 / alpha)
del inner_integral  # to free some memory
outer_integral = np.sum(inner_integral_powered) * dx
print(outer_integral)
```

Comment: Evaluating an integral by mere summation is not the best idea. Simpson would be better. And storing all 2000 x 1000 values is also not a good idea when in fact there is no need to keep a single one. (Not mentioning that you use the sparse representation when your grid is maximally dense !)

Comment: there are a lot of optimizations to be done, that's for sure, like making the integration in smaller sequential patches, and doing an automated step convergence criteria, however because the speed of the algorithm depends on how it's implemented (C vs python), it'll actually be faster to increase the number of points, than doing the Simpson integration in python, all and all, it's just a demonstration of how to do a 2D numerical integration with extra operations in between, and i don't want to turn this into an optimization post.

Comment: also np.meshgrid(sparse=True) doesn't create a sparse matrix, it creates a broadcastable matrix, which will expand to a dense matrix once it's used in any operation.

Comment: "it'll actually be faster to increase the number of points": the function is computed by Python code anyway, there is little that you can gain. And I fail to see any benefit of using sparse when you known that you have a dense matrix.

Comment: you should read about numpy library implementation, anyway i was wrong as simpson is also using C, so it's only 5 to 10 times slower than sum, i was expecting it to be even slower than that if it was implemented in python.

Comment: Thanks a lot! As you can see I am not an expert programmer and I had no idea that the unbounded interval of integration could have been a problem. I will definitely try your solution.

Comment: You can say it in any language, as the function is not compiled to native code, it is interpreted and slower than the algorithm that evaluates it.

Comment: numpy functions are in fact compiled to native code, please read its documentation.